# shell, finding property in properties file. Have windows command version

Tags: shell, unix

I'm not that familiar with Linux so I'm having trouble converting the following command into a relatively short Linux version.

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,2 delims==" %i IN ('findstr /i "version" test.properties') DO
```

When googling I seem to always stumble upon overly long solutions.

Comment: ... Yeah. Scrap the code, describe the process.

Comment: What is that supposed to do?  Input file and the output expected would help too :)

Comment: Ah sorry, knew I was forgetting something. I'm trying to retrieve a property called version from the file test.properties. The property file is something along the lines of: 'version = 1.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is equivalent to:

```
for i in $(grep -i "version" test.properties | cut -d= -f2)
do
   echo $i
done
```

Comment: You should strip anything after `;` too and the for loop will break values with whitespace, which I don't know whether the windows version does or not.

Comment: That seems to net an unexpected token do when placing it in a shell file and running it. ` #!/bin/bash
for i in $(grep -i "version" test.properties | cut -d= -f2)
do
   echo $i
done


`

Comment: @Jack you need semicolons if you want to write it on a single line: `for i in $(grep -i "version" test.properties | cut -d= -f2); do echo $i; done`

Comment: It's on multiple lines, but comments don't seem to allow line breaks.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for i in $(grep -i "version" test.properties | cut -d= -f2); do echo $i; nets me an unexpted end of file at line 3. despite the shell file being 2 lines, and the property file being longer + containing the property. Could this be an issue with cygwin? (and using a `#`does not seem to cause a new line.

Comment: @Jack you need a `done` to mark the end of your for loop. Read my answer again.

Comment: @Jack did you include the word done at the end to complete the while do loop?

Comment: That does seem to do the trick, thank you dogbane. Is there a way to make the version an exact match? Because other words containing version are also found?

Comment: @Jack try changing to `grep -iw` to match words.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ne 's/^ *version *= *\([^;]*\).*/\1/p' < test.properties | while read i; do ... done
```

Using `sed` to search the required line and parse out the value at the same time and while read to keep line separation.

Comment: That nets an unexpected end of file?

Answer (score 0):

Next time, show a sample of your test.properties file so that others won't have to guess how it looks like. Also, show your desired output as well.

```
 awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="="}/version/{print $2;exit}' test.properties
```